# Error loading model.json Tensorflow.js, IOHandler provided does not have the `load` method implemented

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow.js

I'm getting the following error when I try to load my trainned model on my web app, the json is reached from the path properly (I've tryed to print with console.log  and it's OK), seems that the problem is when tf.loadLayers try to load it...

**Vue App Code**

```
  import * as tf from '@tensorflow/tfjs';

  export default {
    data(){
      return {
        modelJSON: require('../model/jsmodel/model.json'),
      }
    },
  mounted(){
    this.loadModel();
  },
  methods: {
      async loadModel(){
        this.model = await tf.loadLayersModel(this.modelJSON)
      },
...
```

**Error**

```
models.js?411e:207 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Cannot proceed with model loading because the IOHandler provided does not have the `load` method implemented.
    at loadLayersModelFromIOHandler (models.js?411e:207)
    at loadLayersModelInternal (models.js?411e:190)
    at Module.loadLayersModel (exports.js?79b0:220)
    at _callee$ (SingleTweet.vue?b47c:40)
    at tryCatch (runtime.js?96cf:63)
    at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (runtime.js?96cf:293)
    at Generator.eval [as next] (runtime.js?96cf:118)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (asyncToGenerator.js?1da1:3)
    at _next (asyncToGenerator.js?1da1:25)
    at eval (asyncToGenerator.js?1da1:32)
```

Comment: I encountered exactly the same issue, I tried ES6 import with webpack, it doesn't work as well, I try to check the source code.

Answer (score 1):

I checked the source code and it looks that the proper handler from static files manifesto json of the model imported with ES6 or CommonJS isn't implemented, so as a workaround it worked for me over http, you can place your model to a storage or start local server and disable CORS in a browser for the page where you open your app. I think the issue can be opened on github project.

1. Install http server, e.g.

   npm install http-server -g
2. Launch your dev server

   npm run dev
3. Launch server to serve files from the models folder

   http-server
4. Change this.modelJSON to path to JSON file, in my case

   const modelJSON = 'http://127.0.0.1:8087/model.json'
5. Disable CORS to allow cross-domain requests, there is a plugin to do it.

The model can be placed e.g. to CloudStorage or to any other server with statics.